# Collection View Cell Loading time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview, chess

This my collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath method:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

            ChessBoard *boardView = [[ChessBoard alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.width)];

            boardView.fenString = self.fenArray[indexPath.item];

            [boardView.highlightBoxes addObject:self.lastMoveFromSqiArray[indexPath.item]];
            [boardView.highlightBoxes addObject:self.lastMoveToSqiArray[indexPath.item]];

            NSLog(@"from %@, to %@", self.lastMoveFromSqiArray[indexPath.item], self.lastMoveToSqiArray[indexPath.item]);
            boardView.showCoordinates = NO;
            [boardView baseInit];

            //main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [cell addSubview:boardView];
            });

        });


        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

        return cell;
```

ChessBoard is a UIView subclass which returns a uiview with chessboard drawn in it.

When I run this, the view controller is loaded without any content in cells and it takes too much time to load cells.
Is there any way i can make it better ?

Comment: add a loading screen untill all cells are loaded..
or just try presenting controller and in its completion part make the loader go away...
as if the cells are so many displayed on the screen they will definately take time to load

Comment: but its taking more than 10-15 seconds to load, and that's a lot.

Comment: See, the number of cells displayed on the screen will load definately. You cant stop that.